# dart append data to html on future .then()

Tags: dart

So i have this code:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:json';

class BaseModel {
  Map values;
  String _url;
  // another basic properties

  // constructor defined here

  fetch() {
    var el = document.query('#container');
    HttpRequest.getString(_url).then(
      (result) {
        values = new Map.from(parse(result));
        el.innerHtml = values['name'];
        return result;
      })
  }
}

void main() {
  BaseModel bm = new BaseModel(url: /path/to/test.json);
  bm.fetch();
}
```

And i have a json data like this:

```dart
{
  "name" : "Andrew",
  "age" : 20
}
```

I expect to see "Andrew" on the DOM, but i see nothing. If i change the

`el.innerHtml = "SOME_TEXT"`

then i can see the "SOME_TEXT" text displayed.

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1):

- What do you see in the JavaScript console if you print the name?
- What happens if you add an error handler?

Something along the following lines:

```
    HttpRequest.getString(_url)
      .then((result) {
        values = new Map.from(parse(result));
        print(values['name']);
        el.innerHtml = values['name'];
        return result;
      })
      .catchError((e) => print(e));
```